# Custom Dimension value alway showing up as not set

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to create custom dimension using GTM, dataLayer and GoogleAnalytics.

In GTM, created a user defined variable.
[UserVariable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dyf5.png)

I have something like this in my html page

```
    <script>
function addCategory(){
  dataLayer.push({
      'category' : 'drama'
  }
);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="addCategory()">
```

In Google analytics created custom dimension

[Custom Dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v1tT.png)

In the GTM in tags section, associated the dimension that was created with the user defined variable.

```
Index - 2
Dimension Value - {{category}}
```

In the Preview and Debug mode i can see that value in the Variables section.

category Data Layer Variable string 'drama'

But in Google Analytics i always seeing that value as (not set).

What have i done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any custom definition should be sent with an existing hit. Can you confirm that a pageview or an event is fired after you defined the variable? Check [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164990?hl=en#datalayer) answer that is describing how to send a custom dimension with GTM. In step 3 it is described how to use the Universal Analytics tag to send the custom dimension to GA. I suspect that your custom dimension is never included in an analytics hit that is why you see (not set). 
 Also, I would advise against using variable names such as 'category' in GA because it is resembling a variable 'used' by enhanced ecommerce.

Comment: I did the things that were mentioned in step 3. Associated dimension index that was created in analytics to the custom variable that was created in tag manager.

Comment: If everything is implemented as mentioned in the links, you can use Google Tag Assistant ( https://get.google.com/tagassistant/ ) to detect any inconsistencies. Also, make sure that your dataLayer.push is **complete** before you insert the GTM snippet or you will keep seeing (not set).

Comment: I am doing dataLayer.push after inserting the GTM snippet. Would that be an issue. I am thinking push would append new ones to the existing dataLayer

Comment: It will but to be able to send the data that you pushed in dataLayer to analytics, a ga hit should be sent. Your category value should be populated with the required value before the tag manager snippet is loaded. This can be done as described here https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/data-layer/#crayon-58df6b4992d51134826019 . Or you should send it with a next independent hit.